# What are some popular Row based and Column based databases?

Tags: mysql, database

There are many popular RDBMS, but I am not able to differentiate them between Row based & column based.
(This question is choice based, I don't need review of any database. I just need list by nature of DB)

Comment: meaning you don't have a programming question, making this completely off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List of **Column based DBMS**:

- List item
- Apache HBase
- Apache Kudu
- Apache Parquet
- Calpont InfiniDB
- ClickHouse
- CrateDB
- C-Store
- Druid
- Greenplum Database
- Postgresql cstore_fdw [1]
- Hypertable
- MariaDB ColumnStore
- MapD Technologies
- Metakit
- MonetDB
- RCFile

List of **Row Oriented DBMS**:

- IBM
- Teradata
- Netezza
- DATAllegro

Column oriented DBMS are faster then row oriented. Row based database if your workload is mainly based on aggregates. That's why column based are so effective for data warehousing.

On the other hand if your workload is update/delete heavy then column based can be much slower than row-based databases.